# Infinite sum - alternatives to residue theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, fourier-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm looking at proving the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64k^4+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1+\mathrm{sinh}(\pi/2)}{\mathrm{cosh}(\pi/2)}$$

I know this can be done by finding the residues and taking the sum of their negatives. Curious if anyone knows how to prove it in another way - maybe with Fourier transform? I thought about Parseval's theorem except the denominator isn't a perfect square.

Thanks

Comment: Just a curiosity, but taking the residues of what ?

Comment: $\pi\mathrm{cot}(\pi k)(1/(64k^4+1))$

Comment: That is not a complex function, I do not understand

Comment: $\pi\cot(\pi z)/(64z^2 +1)$

Comment: @Thomas There are then simple poles at the integers with the residues that make up the infinite sum, and also 4 simple poles at $\pm 2\pm 2i$ whose residues give the RHS. The integral round a big square of side $2N+1$ centered at $0$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks now it makes sense to me :)

Comment: Have you looked in the tables for functions with Fourier series coefficients $\frac{1}{8n^2\pm 4n +1}$? We could then use the convolution theorem?

Comment: @ancientmathematician You may be interested in my answer; it's a very non-advanced method :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came up with this method by myself, so there may be other easier or shorter methods. Enjoy (and don't give up-it does end eventually!).

---

We begin first with the following $2$ formulae:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{r^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{1.1}$$
$$\frac{\sinh x}{x}=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{r^2\pi^2}\right).\tag{1.2}$$
Multiplying the $2$ formulae together, we obtain
$$\frac{\sin x \sinh x}{x^2}=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{r^4\pi^4}\right).\tag{1.3}$$
Replace $x$ with $\pi x$.
$$\frac{\sin(\pi x)\sinh(\pi x)}{\pi^2x^2}=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^4}{r^4}\right)=\prod_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{r^4-x^4}{r^4}\right).\tag{1.4}$$

Take the natural logarithm of both sides and differentiate with respect to $x$. This leads us to
$$\pi\cot(\pi x)+\pi\coth(\pi x)-\frac{2}{x}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{-4x^3}{r^4-x^4}$$
and therefore
$$\frac{2-\pi x(\cot(\pi x)+\coth(\pi x))}{4x^4}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^4-x^4}.\tag{1.5}$$
Before continuing, we need to know the following formula which is obtained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsKfyE1w4AQ&t=15s):
$$\cot(x+iy)=\frac{\sin2x}{\cosh 2y-\cos2x}-i\frac{\sinh 2y}{\cosh2y-\cos2x}.\tag{1.6}$$
Now we let $x=ze^{i\pi/4}$, so that $x^4=-z^4$:
$$\frac{2-\pi ze^{i\pi/4} (\cot(\pi ze^{i\pi/4})+\coth(\pi ze^{i\pi/4} ))}{-4z^4}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^4+z^4}.\tag{1.7}$$
And now let $z=\frac{1}{64^{1/4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$:
$$\frac{\pi  \frac{\sqrt2}{4}e^{i\pi/4}(\cot(\pi \frac{\sqrt2}{4}e^{i\pi/4})+\coth(\pi \frac{\sqrt2}{4}e^{i\pi/4} ))-2}{4/64}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^4+1/64}=64\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}.\tag{1.8}$$
Let's deal with the rather nasty looking expression inside the $\cot$ and $\coth$:
$$\pi \frac{\sqrt2}{4}e^{i\pi/4}=\pi \frac{\sqrt2}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
So we have
$$\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}(1+i)(\cot(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4})+\coth(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4} ))-2}{4}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}.\tag{1.9}$$
Now, using equation $(1.6)$ we can see that $$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}-i\frac{\sinh \frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
and using the identity $\coth z=i\cot iz$ we can also see that
$$\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}-i\frac{1}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
and therefore
$$\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+\coth\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1+\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-i).\tag{1.10}$$
Substituting this values into equation $(1.9)$ we can see that
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}=\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1+\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}(1-i)(1+i)-2}{4}\tag{1.11}$$
which simplifies to
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}=\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1+\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}-2}{4}.\tag{1.12}$$

---

Now for the final part. Firstly, note that
$$\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}=1+2\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}.$$
Hence,

$$\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}=1+\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1+\sinh\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cosh\frac{\pi}{2}}-2}{2}\tag{2.1}$$
and *finally*

## $$\mathbf{\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{64r^4+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1+\sinh(\pi/2)}{\cosh(\pi/2)}}$$
as required!

---

I hope that was useful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :) I have enjoyed working this out enormously, thanks for the challenge!!

Comment: Nice work!.....

Comment: I like it! Very interesting (but I suppose not surprising) how it hovers around $\pi\cot\pi z$ and the $8$-th roots of unity, just like the residue calculus solution.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks! I'm still in high school so I don't know anything about residue calculus. Do you know anywhere where I could learn it?

Comment: @RonGordon thank you! It means a lot, coming from someone as knowledgeable as you.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent. That's a big ask. When I was still teaching it was a 2nd year topic at Oxford, and the books we used supposed that people had done a year's serious real analysis. Hilary A Priestley, Intro to Complex Analysis was one such book. If you have access to a library with maths books it's worth looking in Engineering Maths books to see if they have something on "contour integration" - usually they are more computational in approach. Or if you can find a copy of Whittaker and Watson in a library it is worth looking at the exercises to see the sort of results one can get. Good luck.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks a lot for the advice, I didn't realize it was that advanced. If I know Spivak's Calculus very well would that be a sufficient prerequisite do you think?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent : try it and see, I reckon. I certainly know that it is/used to be possible for physics/engineering students to acquire a working knowledge of residue calculus in their first year; but just as a bag of clever tricks. So it depends what you are trying to achieve: mathematical understanding or manipulative fluency. (It has to be said that there's less call for clever manipulation these days. Although it's still quite fun.)

Comment: Very nice! Sorry, I just got the email that I had answers to my question. Thanks for the approach.

Comment: @user3527708 no problem, I'm really glad I could help :) Where did you get the problem from? Are there any other similar probelms?I loved doing it.